# What is the best way to handle SOAP type Exceptions in python

Tags: python, xml, soap

In case the user enters data that is NOT on the web server being accessed by a WSDL, i get an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns2:Body>
      <ns1:getFieldsForEdit>
         <in0 xsi:type="ns3:string">FmofSimScl</in0>
         <in1 xsi:type="ns3:string">QA-65000</in1>
      </ns1:getFieldsForEdit>
   </ns2:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.rpc.jira.atlassian.com" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns2:Body>
      <ns1:getIssue>
         <in0 xsi:type="ns3:string">FmofSimScl</in0>
         <in1 xsi:type="ns3:string">QA-65000</in1>
      </ns1:getIssue>
   </ns2:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/check_jira.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/check_jira.py", line 12, in main
    commit_text_verified = verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"'))
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/check_jira.py", line 35, in verify_commit_text
    if CheckForJiraIssueRecord(m_args) == 0:
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/check_jira.py", line 58, in CheckForJiraIssueRecord
    issue = com.run(command_name, logger, jira_env, my_args)
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/jira.py", line 1367, in run
    return self.commands[command].dispatch(logger, jira_env, args)
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/jira.py", line 75, in dispatch
    results = self.run(logger, jira_env, args)
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/jira.py", line 174, in run
    logger.error(decode(e))
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/jira.py", line 1434, in decode
    str = e.faultstring
AttributeError: 'WebFault' object has no attribute 'faultstring'
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: pretxncommit.jira hook exited with status 1
```

Is there a way to handle this so i can write my own error string , or a warning message instead of all this. If i turn OFF stdout i dont get the xml data, but i still get:

```
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: pretxncommit.jira hook exited with status 1
```

which is from mercurial, but would be nice to have a an error string appended to it like
warnings.warn("%s does not exist"%issue_id)

ok, i looked in jira.py
and changed on line 1434 :
str = e.faultstring
to
str = e.fault

and got:

```
faultcode = "soapenv:Server.userException"
   faultstring = "com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemotePermissionException: This issue does not exist or you don't have permission to view it."
   detail = 
      (detail){
         com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemotePermissionException = ""
         hostname = "JIRA"
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was fixed in jira.py :
change he decode function to:

```
def decode(e):
    """Process an exception for useful feedback"""
    # TODO how to log the fact it is an error, but allow info to be unchanged?
    # TODO now fault not faultstring?
    # The faultType class has faultcode, faultstring and detail
    str = e.fault
    if str == 'com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemotePermissionException':
        return "This issue does not exist or you don't have permission to view it"
    return e.fault
```

instead of :

```
def decode(e):
    """Process an exception for useful feedback"""
    # TODO how to log the fact it is an error, but allow info to be unchanged?
    # TODO now fault not faultstring?
    # The faultType class has faultcode, faultstring and detail
    str = e.faultstring
    if str == 'java.lang.NullPointerException':
        return "Invalid issue key?"
    return e.faultstring
```